# Use SumIf Worksheet function on numbers formatted as text

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dynamic sheet that is kind of a data dump. It is created with some code I will not show here, but one of the issues is that some monetary cells are considered as text and not numbers.

Therefore, the following line will return 0 even when there are plenty of numbers that should be counted (in this example I check if the text in column `F` is the string `arg` and add the corresponding value in `I` to the sum if yes:

```
Application.SumIf(dumpSheet.Range("F1:F10000"), arg, dumpSheet.Range("I1:I10000"))
```

[image]

I get that little tooltip asking if I want to change to a number format, but the macro recorder doesn't record anything when I use it to say yes. So Excel does recognise it is potentially a number. Right click>Format>Currency or numeric doesn't change anything in this case, it still considers it as text and the green corner tooltip stays there.

Now I know I could replace the SumIf by using `loops` to go remove the $ sign, for this but it would make it pretty damn slow. A faster way would be to use Find and FindNext but still, I feel like nothing can be faster than the worksheet functions.

How can I convert the entire column of currency values to numbers before using my worksheet function? As it is now, the value of the cells is something like `363,27 $`.

Comment: Text to columns and split on space

Comment: How much time are you going to lose using a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two ways:

- if your currency-data is e.g. in column B2:B100 , add a new column with the formula `=B2*1` and drag it down to copy the original column. This will attempt to turn the string into a number. Since you only multiply it by one the value itself won't change. If it does not help straight away, use text-functions like =Replace to get rid of currency symbols, then multiply the whole thing with 1 again to turn it into a number.
- if you add in this kind of data often try using the "Data - Get new Data from" feature from the menu in Excel 2016 or using the Power Query plugin (comes directly from Microsoft) for Excel 2010-2013. Here you can just convert the column to decimal/whole number.
  You can choose between excel files, text files, databases and much more. The tools lets you convert your original data into the desired types, choose columns to keep, clean up empty or unused rows, filter stuff and much more with a simple GUI. Whenever you get new data in the source, just click "Update all" and your target table gets updated in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This short routine should get those text-that-looks-like-currency into true numerical currency. VBA is very EN-US centric with regards to regional settings so you have a baseline to strive towards.

[image: crappy_currency]

Note the default left-alignment of text values despite any number or currency cell formatting.

Run this fix-it sub procedure.

```
Option Explicit

Sub fixitCurrency()
    Dim dumpSheet As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long, fnr As Variant

    Set dumpSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    fnr = Array(Chr(44), Chr(46), _
                Chr(36), vbNullString, _
                Chr(32), vbNullString)

    With dumpSheet.Range("I1:I10000").Cells
        'loop through the find and replace array
        For r = LBound(fnr) To UBound(fnr) Step 2
            .Replace what:=fnr(r), replacement:=fnr(r + 1), _
                     lookat:=xlPart, matchbyte:=True
        Next r

        'this may not be necessary but it doesn't take long
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                       FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)

        'restore the non-EN-US number format now that they are true numbers
        .NumberFormat = "# ##0.00 $"
    End With

End Sub
```

[image: crappy_currency2]

Note the default right-alignment of true numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim v, arg, dumpSheet As Worksheet

arg = "Y"

Set dumpSheet = ActiveSheet

v = dumpSheet.Evaluate("=SUM((F$1:F$10000=""" & arg & """)*IF(I1:I10000<>""""," & _
                       "SUBSTITUTE(I$1:I$10000,"" $"",""""),0))")

Debug.Print v
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are only using VBA to perform this one calculation, and would prefer to just use a native Excel formula, you could use the following:

```
=Sum(If("F1:F10000"=arg,Value(Substitute("I1:I10000","$","")),0))
```

where arg is whatever value you are trying to check for.

(You would need to enter the formula using Ctrl-Shift-Enter, rather than just Enter.)